# Administrative Delay in Making Formal Offers

Tags: job-offer, internship

I have applied to a competitive research internship program in the US. I was told about two weeks ago that I have been shortlisted and it says on their website that the selection outcome will be released today. However, instead of getting a clear yes or no, I was told today that I am still on the shortlist, but there has been administrative delay in making any formal offers and I should hear from them again in a week or so.

Does this suggest that I have been placed on a waiting list, while the selection committee wait for confirmations from the first choice candidates?

Comment: You can;t possibly know what someone is thinking or how a specific company operates. I feel this question cant be "Answered" and even opinions would fail to provide guidance.

Comment: I understand. I just wanted to know if this is a common thing to do/say when committees need to wait for confirmations from their top choice candidates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally, taking people at their word is a decent strategy.  Is it possible that they've reached out to their top choices and are waiting to hear whether they've accepted before they tell their backup candidates?  Sure.  Is it possible that someone that is involved with the committee that is making the decision got sick and had to take a couple of days off or that someone got busy and had to move a meeting?  That's also entirely possible.  They've told you that it was an administrative delay.  Unless you have some reason to doubt their word or your behavior would change if you knew the "real story", take them at their word.

Comment: Exactly.  It could be as simple as a key decision-maker had to take a couple of sick days.